# Restore previous Vim search term?

Tags: vim, search, keymap, highlighting

Is it possible to save/restore Vim search terms in a `map`?

For instance, I have the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
map ,/ :s/^/\/\//<CR>
```

If I have turned on highlighting (`:set hls`) previously in the session, then when I invoke the above mapping the first column of every line will be highlighted.

Would it be possible to instead save the current search term (if any), then perform the search/replace, then restore the last search term (if any) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the substitute command into a function you won't override your search highlighting. See `:h function-search-undo`

```
map <leader>/ :call SomeName()<cr>
function! SomeName()
  s/^/\/\//
endfunction
```

P.S.

I assume `,` is your leader key.

Comment: I had to remove the `<CR>` from the function to fix an error about trailing characters, but other than that this is perfect.

Comment: Opps, I'll update my answer.